# WCF Learning material

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I wanna learn WCF Is there any site where i can find free video tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: Without posting an answer as it would require more than a one-liner, look in to [wsDualHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751522.aspx) and having clients subscribe to the service and the service pushing updates back.

Answer (score 0):

WCFTutorial.net

This site teaches you everything from basic to advance